# WPF Textbox and Label are overlapping

Tags: c#, wpf

I am learning WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) on Visual Studio 2013. I have an issue with the layout of elements. I am using *stackpanel* and *grid* for element layout. Here is the simple layout which i have created:

```
... code omitted....

    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ersStackPanel}">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource ersGrid}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="497*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Elector's record scrapper" Style="{StaticResource ersHeadLabel}" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource ersGrid}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="347*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="VS" Style="{StaticResource ersLabel}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="VS" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ersTextBox}" />
            <Label Content="EV" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ersLabel}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="EV" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ersTextBox}" />
            <Label Content="ENo." Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ersLabel}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="ENo" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ersTextBox}" />
            <Label Content="Select" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ersLabel}"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="10" Background="White"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

... code omitted...
```

**Style Resource**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ersTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ersLabel" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ersHeadLabel" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ersLabel}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ersStackPanel" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="497"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="44"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ersGrid" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="44"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The problem is that all elements (Label, TextBox ..) are overlapping each other, Why they are not positioning like a stack (one after another) ??

Comment: because your grid has no rows and you are relying on your set Heights, Margins and Alignments to place your elements, if you want to "Stack" elements put them inside a `StackPanel` not a `Grid`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using grid layout you need to define rows and columns. If u don't define them, XAML will stack them  one over the other. The last element defined will be the visible one.

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Text="A"/> // The first is assumed that it is Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="B"/>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="C"/>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="D"/>
</Grid>
```

This will look like this:

A B

C D

In your code the problem is that you are setting elements to the second, third and fourth row, but you didn't defined the rows in the first place.

Also remember that enumeration is Zero-based (First row is actually 0).